# Vanity URLS & Xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I understand that there may be other questions regarding vanity urls but everyone i see has a different code that i guess does the same job. Therefor i do not understand what rules are best for my personal question, that being said here is my question.

I simply want to create this,

127.0.0.1/website/profile.php?id=1

To this,

127.0.0.1/website/profile/Admin

My sub questions are also,

1. I understand the .htaccess file has to be in the root directory, but is that the root of my website or my xampp htdocs?(e.g c:/xampp/htdocs/ or c:/xampp/htdocs/website)
2. Using php should i make the conversion between id to username for the URLS on a seperate file then redirect to the requested user's page?

Thank you for reading, i just can't seem to get my head around .htaccess!

Comment: The best code for your case is the one that works. Have none of the solutions worked for you?

Comment: No im afraid not, also because i want it to convert username to id then display the page, because my profile.php only accepts a id in the $_GET (profile.php?id=1) Im not sure weather i should redirect the .htaccess to a small file that will convert it for me then redirect to the correct profile or something else?

Comment: That's how it will work under the hood in most (every?) solutions. The user can access `profile/Username` and the script will work just the same as if they had accessed `profile.php?id=X`.

Comment: Username is different from ID, E.g Username = Admin, ID = 1. There for  you would have to convert it surely?

Comment: Well yes, but that's a PHP-side problem that depends on your implementation, not a htaccess problem.

Comment: Thats why i asked it as a sub question and included php in the tags :)

Comment: It's also a question no-one can answer without details because it depends on how you've implemented the usernames.

Comment: What more details shall i add specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Root directory of your website.
2. No need for redirects. The way it works is that you can map every section of your URL to a URL parameter. For example, `http://localhost/profile/Admin` is really interpreted as `http://localhost/website/profile.php?username=Admin`.  Only users will see the vanity URL; PHP will still see the URL parameters. In your case, the .htaccess rule will look something like `^profile/([0-9]+)$ profile.php?username=$1` (I obviously don't know for sure since I don't know the architecture of you site).

---

On a side note you might find Virtual Hosts interesting. It's a way of being able to create your own local domain for your site, for example `http://my-local-website` instead of using `http://localhost/website` or waiting to test in production.

More info here: http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/

Comment: Great info! Thank you. I currently have my profile.php set up to only accept a ID, profile.php?id=1 rather than profile.php?username=Admin. Would you suggest i change all of my code to work around vanity-urls or shall i create another file that will convert username to ID and then redirect to the profile.php?id=1. for example,

profile/admin ->func.convert.php?username=admin -> grabs id of admin  and redirects to profile.php?id=1

Comment: If you redirect the user, you'd be almost defeating the purpose of the vanity URL. Either change `id` to `usernamme` (which should also be unique), or just use id *instead* of username, like `htttp://localhost/website/profile/1`.

Comment: Ah okay i didnt know it would actually go to the redirected raw link, i see where i was going wrong now, I will have to hard code it into profile.php so that it accepts usernames, Thanks Ayman!